# How to show all rows on table with using Datatable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I work with datatable library, and i want to show all rows on tapping on the separate button.

I try to use few methods but its not working.

My code:

```
if (val != '') {
    $('#' + tableId + '').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], // this is not working, showing default values
        searchPanes: {
            layout: 'columns-' + length + ''
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            searchPanes: {
                show: true
            },
            targets: '_all'
        }],

        dom: 'Pfrtip'
    });
    $('.dtsp-searchPanes').children().each(function (i, obj) {
        if (!val.includes(i)) $(this).hide();
        else $(this).show();
    });
} else {
    $('#' + tableId + '').DataTable({
        destroy: true
    });
}

$("#showAll").on("click", function () {
   //here i need func
});
```

I try to use this parameter:

```
'iDisplayLength': 100
```

But this is not working for me, plus I need to have this possibility not like parameter but like separate function.

Comment: which data table jquery version are you using?

Comment: @MohsinMarui DataTables-1.10.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`page.len()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()) API call to dynamically change the page length.

```
$("#showAll").on("click", function () {
   $( '#' + tableId + '').dataTable().api().page.len( -1 ).draw();
});
```